# alternative to 'rename' command in CentOS 5.9

Tags: centos, rename

I need to rename all files whose name contains the substring `200at` and substitute it with `200_at`. 
In Ubuntu, I would do:

```
find . -type f -name '*200at*' -exec rename -n 's/200at/200_at/' {} \;
```

In  CentOS (version 5.9) it doesn't work. The command `rename` doesn't seem to support perl expressions and the above command does nothing at all.

Any ideas for an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with CentOS, we always used the mv (move) command for renaming things. ie:

mv 200at ./200_at

hope that works as your alternative.

Comment: Ok, and how do I do pattern matching with `mv`? your example renames a file whose name is `200at`, while in my case that should be a substring of the full filename. I found a few examples and it wasnt the regex syntax...

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102647/how-to-rename-multiple-files-in-single-command-or-script-in-unix

Comment: i'm actually a bit rusty on my shell scripting. someone else should help out more. sorry about that. I just remembered offhand that 'mv' is the standard tool for renaming files in linux.